# wordpress syntax highlighting: updating post ruins characters like "&"

Tags: wordpress

Im usig [WP-syntax plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) to show code in my posts. The problem is everytime I hit the "Update post" button, characters like & turn into &amp ; and I need to go back to the HTML editor to change it once more, since the code appears between  tags.

What could I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you use the visual editor ? if you use it, I advise you dont to use it for update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Use wp-syntaxhighlighter.1.7.2 which worked for me ......may be works for you too. Look at the demo [here.](http://prashiddha.com.np)

And Its totally free of cost...............And the best syntax highlighter I ever have tried.

Thank You.